# Partition and block in sparkit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, pyspark

I am trying to implement the scikit- learn Extra tree classifier algorithm by calling it form Spark Python API. Since Spark works on RDDs and the scikit algorithm expects only arrays,matrices or dataframes, I came across sparkit learn (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sparkit-learn) for this purpose. However, I did not understand the concept of partitions and blocks that sparkit uses.